# Notice: Undefined variable: userok in C:\xampp\htdocs\Photox\Home\login.php on line 116

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Este es un pequeño programa para iniciar sesión, pero al querer probar ingresar el usuario y contraseña que estan en la base de datos, marca un error que dice que esa variable está indefinida
Tengo un error de variable indefinida cuando si lo está
Notice: Undefined variable: userok in C:\xampp\htdocs\Photox\Home\login.php on line 116

CODIGO PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
   echo "<center>Error el usuario o contraseña no coinciden</center>";
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])) {
  require("php/conexion.php");
  $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
  $password = md5($_POST['contra']);
  $consulta = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
  if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
     while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) { //Guardo los valores en 2 variables
        $userok = $row['username'];  //Aqui estoy definiendo la variable
        $passok = $row['password'];
     }
     $resultado->close();
  }
  $mysqli->close();
  if(isset($username) && isset($password)) {
    if($username == $userok && $password == $passok) { //Aqui me sale el error
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['logueado'] = TRUE;
       header("location: bueno.html");
    }
    else {
       header("location: malo.html");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

CODIGO HTML

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-single-02"></i></span>
         </div>
         <input id="user" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" type="text">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-lock-circle-open"></i></span>
         </div>
         <input id="contra" name="contra" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" name="entrar" class="btn btn-primary my-4">Iniciar sesión</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: No veo error ahí: `$userok = $row['username'];  //Aqui esta el error`  ... ¿Seguro que esa es la línea `116` del archivo `login.php`? Es imposible que justo donde defines la variable te de el error de *Undefined variable*. Ese error debe estar ocurriendo **en un ámbito donde `$userok` no es visible**.

Comment: Tienes razón, confundí la línea, el error está en `if($username == $userok && $password == $passok) {` donde no encuentra la variable que está definida. Ya modifico la pregunta

Comment: Lo dicho. Tú estás definiendo `$userok` dentro de este ámbito:  `if(isset($_POST['entrar'])) {` y no solamente ahí, sino también dentro de otro ámbito interno a él: `if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {` si el código no pasa **por uno Y por otro**, la variable no será definida, que es lo que está ocurriendo. Un modo de resolverlo es definiendo la variable fuera de todos los `if` con un valor predeterminado, por ejemplo: `$userok=NULL;` Y, puede que tengas el mismo problema con `$passok`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchísimas gracias, ya los definí fuera de los ciclos y me funcionó, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PHP las variables son de ámbito local. Significa que si defines una variable dentro de un `if`, una función, un bucle, etc., la misma no estará disponible por defecto fuera de ese ámbito.

Por ejemplo en tu código estás definiendo `$userok` **dentro de dos ámbitos** que en este caso son dos `if`.

```
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])) {
  if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
     while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) { //Guardo los valores en 2 variables
        $userok = $row['username'];  //Aqui estoy definiendo la variable

...
```

Si el código no entra **en uno Y otro ámbito**, la variable no se definiría (el `while` podemos decir que no cuenta como ámbito, pero si por algún motivo el código no entrase en él, la variable tampoco se definiría).

Una forma de resolver esto sería definiendo la variable fuera de los `if` y del `while`, con un valor por defecto. Por ejemplo:

```
$userok=NULL;

    if(isset($_POST['entrar'])) {
      if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
         while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) { //Guardo los valores en 2 variables
            $userok = $row['username'];  //Aqui estoy ASIGNANDO nuevo valor a la variable
    
    ...
```

Lo mismo podría estar ocurriendo con tu variable `$passok`.